# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping Relationships Across Schemas

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, schema, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an object Site, like this

```
public class Site
{
    public virtual int SiteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Options Options { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an options object

```
public class Options
{
    public virtual int OptionsId { get; set; }

    private int SiteId { get; set; }
    private Site Site { get; set; }
}
```

The caveat here is that I cannot add any fields to the `Site` table.  In the past, I have done a mapping like this

```
public class SiteMap : ClassMap<Site>
{
    public SiteMap()
    {
        Table("Sites");

        HasOne<Options>(x => x.Options)
                .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class OptionsMap : ClassMap<Options>
{
    public OptionsMap()
    {
        Table("Options");

        Id(Reveal.Property<Options>("SiteId")).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Site");

        HasOne<Site>(Reveal.Member<Options, Site>("Site"))
                .Constrained()
                .ForeignKey();
    }
}
```

This always worked great.  Except one small snaffu - my options table is in a different schema.  I have added `Schema("MySchema");` to the mapping for my `Options` object, but when I try to get a site, I get nothing back.  I am pretty sure my problem is the `.ForeignKey();`.

How to I map this when the two related objects are in different schemas?

Comment: have you checked that there are matching Site rows in the db? if it would be a wrong schema you would get a sql-exception stating that the table (in the wrong schema) could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another mapping option:

```
class SiteMap : ClassMap<Site>
{
    public SiteMap()
    {
        Join("MySchema.Options", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("SiteId");
            join.Component(x => x.Options, c => c.Map(x => x.Prop1));
        });
    }
}
```